# How to prevent installation of software with known vulnerabilities in Linux?

Tags: linux, installation, vulnerabilities

Is there any tool for Linux which scans software during installation for known vulnerabilities (weaknesses that could later be exploited)?

In addition to scanning software after it is installed, I want to know if software with known vulnerabilities can be prevented from getting installed.  For example, a vulnerability was discovered in Java not long ago and later corrected.  While it had a known vulnerability, it would have been useful to prevent installation.

Comment: That's what repositories are for. Get your packages from the stable branch and you should be good.

Comment: This is normally handled by only installing software from the official package repositories. And you prevent people bypassing this by restricting access to the root account or to sudo.

Comment: Well, may be i am not clear in above question. I can prevent normal users to install anything by restricting access to root account or sudo, but what i want to do is, even when root is installing a software, first it should be scanned by some "tool" for any possible vulnerabilities. Even root should be informed about the associated vulnerability with the package.

Comment: it's not the software that's vulnerable, it's the system. Changed title to reflect that.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Ultimately, it is the system that's the victim.  However some software is vulnerable to certain type of attacks (that could happen later, not necessarily an issue of downloading infected software).  PUPs are a completely different issue.  That term usually applies to stuff like crapware that is bundled with something else, often installed surreptitiously.  An example of what this question refers to would be the recent vulnerability discovered in Java and later fixed.  The question is about a tool to recognize known vulnerabilities and prevent installation.

Comment: @fixer1234 - I'm aware that PUP isn't the best description, but it really isn't the software that's vulnerable to what is about to be installed, it's the system. Pure semantics, but the software you are installing is the potential threat, not the vulnerability, even if it's because the software has vulnerabilities of its own.

Comment: @Mehul - Several of us have taken stabs at clarifying or focusing the question, but it's your question.  If it doesn't reflect your intended meaning, please re-edit as necessary.

Comment: @fixer1234 - You got the question correctly. To make it more clear, think about an example like, a user installing an older version of application which was vulnerable to some attacks and it was fixed in later versions. I am looking for a tool which can prevent all such software installation and prompt user about vulnerabilities associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you have repositories, they permit open software developpers to push their software. User can then use them by downloading them from repositories. As software is all open source, it is peer reviewed by the community plus the repositories maintainers normally have some sort of anti-virus software that checks the content.

That said normally package from the repositories are safe. So install only software from there.